# How to implement the copy method of the decorator of a generic class?

Tags: c#, generics, copy, decorator

Imagine you have a generic interface that defines a generic value and a copy constructor like this (replacing ICloneable):

```cs
// T: type of value to hold, TU: type of the class itself
interface ICopyable<T,TU> where TU: ICopyable<T,TU> {
    T Value { get; set; }
    TU Copy();
}
```

This could be implemented by a boolean value holder like this:

```cs
class BooleanHolder : ICopyable<Boolean, BooleanHolder> {
    public BooleanHolder Copy() { 
        return new BooleanHolder(){ Value = Value }; 
    }
}
```

Now comes the question: How would you define a decorator class that holds another ICopyable? My not working idea was:

```cs
class DecoratingHolder<T,TU> : ICopyable<ICopyable<T,TU>, DecoratingHolder<T,TU>> {
    public DecoratingHolder<T,TU> Copy {
        // won't compile as Value is of type T and not of type ICopyable<T,TU> 
        // as I expected - why is that?
        return new DecoratingHolder<T,TU>(){ Value = Value.Copy };
    }
}
```

Note that I called `Copy` to also have the value of type `ICopyable<T,TU>` copied, this is on purpose to ensure deep copies.

So what do I have to change to make this structure work?

Answer (score 3):

You might just need to add a constraint. You define that `ICopyable<T, TU> where TU : ICopyable<T, TU>` but in your `DecoratingHolder`, you never explicitly constraint `TU` as such on `DecoratingHolder`.

More specifically, I think it's this part of the line:

```
class DecoratingHolder<T,TU> : ***ICopyable<ICopyable<T,TU>***
```

That's causing the issue. You're defining a `ICopyable<T,TU>` type, but `TU` has not been constrained to be `ICopyable<T, TU>`. (one might be able to *infer* that from the rest of the class declaration/inheritance, but the compiler doesn't) Once you add the constraint, then the compiler *knows* that `Value` is a compatible `ICopyable<T,TU>` type.

This compiles fine for me (had to fix some other minor things with the pseudocode you provided):

```
class DecoratingHolder<T,TU> : ICopyable<ICopyable<T,TU>, DecoratingHolder<T,TU>> 
    where TU : ICopyable<T,TU>
{
    public ICopyable<T,TU> Value { get; set; }

    public DecoratingHolder<T,TU> Copy() {
        return new DecoratingHolder<T, TU>(){ Value = Value };
    }
}
```

EDIT: In retrospect, do you even need that constraint on `ICopyable`? Seems to not do much as you already generically define the outgoing type anyway. Unless you have code elsewhere that depends on the fact that it returns `ICopyable<T, TU>` for some reason (it would inherently anyway as it would return a strongly typed `TU` or `BooleanHolder` or `DecoratingHolder`) then consider dumping it.

```
interface ICopyable<T,TU>
{
    T Value { get; set; }
    TU Copy();
}

class BooleanHolder : ICopyable<Boolean, BooleanHolder> 
{
    public bool Value { get; set; }
    public BooleanHolder Copy() { 
        return new BooleanHolder(){ Value = Value }; 
    }
}

class DecoratingHolder<T,TU> : ICopyable<ICopyable<T,TU>, DecoratingHolder<T,TU>> 
{
    public ICopyable<T,TU> Value { get; set; }

    public DecoratingHolder<T,TU> Copy() {
        return new DecoratingHolder<T, TU>(){ Value = Value };
    }
}
```

EDIT: From your comment requiring a deep copy, keep the constraints then (you'll need them), and invoke `Copy` on `Value` (sorry, I must have missed that detail)

```
class DecoratingHolder<T,TU> : ICopyable<ICopyable<T,TU>, DecoratingHolder<T,TU>> 
    where TU : ICopyable<T,TU>
{
    public ICopyable<T,TU> Value { get; set; }

    public DecoratingHolder<T,TU> Copy() {
        return new DecoratingHolder<T, TU>(){ Value = Value.Copy() };
    }
}
```

The `Copy` methods for any given class should then make sure they perform a deep copy. (I would suggest renaming `Copy` to `DeepCopy` if your framework *needs* them to be deep copy and you don't want implementations to do shallows accidentally)

Comment: @ChrisSinclair Ah, sorry I just noticed that I forget to mention the necessity of realizing deep copies. Would you adapt your answer

Comment: @Bastian Sorry, I glazed over that detail. I added another edit.

Answer (score 0):

A cast worked for me:

```
    public DecoratingHolder<T, TU> Copy()
    {
        return new DecoratingHolder<T, TU>() { Value = (ICopyable<T, TU>)Value.Copy() };
    }
```

I guess in this context the compiler doesn't go as far as to establish that `TU` and `ICopyable<T, TU>` is the same thing.